# Sort or reverse an Hashmap Arraylist

Tags: java, sorting

I've been practicing Java code challenge.

Here's my code

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> user = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> user1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String , String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String , String>>();

user.put("name", "dave");
user.put("age", "27");
user.put("hobby", "guitar");

user1.put("name", "adam");
user1.put("age", "15");
user1.put("hobby", "sports");

list.add(user);
list.add(user1);

System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Output:

```
 [{name=dave, age=27, hobby=guitar}, {name=adam, age=15, hobby=sports}]
```

Is there anyway I can sort or reverse this arraylist by using any key in the hashmap for example sort by name value or sort by age value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"... Is there anyway I can sort or reverse this arraylist by using any key in the hashmap for example sort by name value or sort by age value? ..."*

To reverse the *List*, utilize the *[Collection#reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))* method.

```java
Collections.reverse(list);
```

And for sorting, use the *[List#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator))* and *[Comparator#comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function))* methods.

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get("name")));
```

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.get("age")));
```

Output, for each routine.

```
[{name=adam, age=15, hobby=sports}, {name=dave, age=27, hobby=guitar}]
```

Comment: Or [`List#reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) in Java 21+. See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

Comment: Caution:  comparing `x.get("age")` may not behave as expected.  Should an age of "8" come before or after an age of "15"?